# Custom queries in Spring with JPA

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-boot, h2

I have created a webapp similiar to the tutorial here:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ .

I have added postgresql db and everything works fine. I have a basic query findByUsername(String name) in my repository which works fine. My problem is, I am for some reason unable to create custom queries e.g

`"SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`.

Lets say i make a test where I just want to get the value of this statement. And by unable I mean I don't know how :)

My google results suggested my to add this to my class

`@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;`

and then create queries on that. But `entityManager` is never initialized for some reason, return null always. Is this the right way and I'm just missing something? Also tried to add `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` and use JdbcTemplate but was also null.

**EDIT**

My problem was too little knowledge of Spring.

I had a class like this and tried to use Autowire in there.

```
public class Person {
@Autowire
MyRepo myRepo;
private String p;
public Person(String p) {
    this.p = p;
}
```

As I understood later, Spring doesn't pick this up. I called out this class in a RestController with `Person per = new Person("string");`.
The solution I made was to Autowire MyRepo in my RestController class and my Person contstructor looked like this

```
public Person(String p, MyRepo myRepo) {
this.p = p;
this.myRepo = myRepo;
}
```

Removed the autowire in Person class. This way I managed to get myRepo initialized in Person class and use it there. This isn't the best soution for my problem.

My second problem. After i got this working, I tried to autowire EntityManager the same to my Person class. Just replaced MyRepo with EntityManager and it was also initialized. Now the problem is with my next code line  `Integer i = (Integer) em.createNativeQuery("select 1", Integer.class).getSingleResult();`. Here I get an error **javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer**.
The purpose of this statement is to make a simple query to my DB, to if it responds.

Comment: Why the `h2` tag?

Comment: Aah, forgot to mention, also have h2 dependency. Don't know, if this is relevant here.

Comment: `@PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;`. JPA is quite a complex beast. And Spring and Spring-data-JPA comes on top of it. You'd better read documentation before diving into it.

Comment: Tried that, still return null.

Comment: You'll have to post your code.

Comment: Do i need have a percistance.xml in my project or spring and jpa will take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to autowire the `EntityManager`, Spring takes care of all this for you.

Instead in your repository you need to define a new method and annotate it with `@Query`.

Example:

```
@Query(value = "select current_timestamp from #{#entityName} u")
String findTimestamp();
```

You can find furhter information about using `@Query` in the spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.

Comment: Yes, this is one way I thought of doing that. But this means, I have to Autowire to some particular repository. Looking for a way to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was:

```
Integer i = (Integer) em.createNativeQuery("select 1").getSingleResult();
```

Just removed the Integer.class part from NatviveQuert. I guess, if I had wanted it to be there, I should have made a new bean for Integer.
Overall this is not the best practice in Spring but it solved my problem.